# What is the PHP function which makes the same action as the MySQL command "SET NAMES utf8"?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute the MySQL command `SET NAMES 'utf8'` from PHP. How to do that ?

Comment: Are you trying to run that SQL Query on MySQL via PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever database library you are using, e.g. `$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")` or `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")`.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`mysql_set_charset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php), assuming you're using the `mysql_` functions.

If you're using PDO, [it's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php):

```
new PDO('...', 'user', 'pass',
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

Otherwise, you can just run `SET NAMES 'utf8'` as a regular query, but the above are the preferred ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to encode from/to utf8 then use [utf8_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.utf8-encode.php) or [iconv](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

MySql construct `SET NAMES 'utf8'` is tells mysql server that client using utf8 encode

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) function in php

```
<?php 
$link1 = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1',TRUE); 
$link2 = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1',TRUE); 

mysql_selectdb('db1',$link1); 
mysql_selectdb('db2',$link2); 

mysql_set_charset('latin1',$link1); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link2); 
?>
```